# Read file/image from local drive in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

Just wanted to know is it possible to access/read a given file(if full filepath is enabled) using Javascript in HTML or any other technique.

I am quite new in HTML 5.

Thanks in advance

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

Answer (score 2):

in HTML5 user allow you to process local files(reading only). See [here](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/)

XMLHttpRequest object can be used to read files also

```
var txt = '';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.readyState==4){
    txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","abc.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: where should we put the file in order to read it please

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open()-method

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (& limited), but not recommended.. [There](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=5bqmy3goIHc) you go :)